# How to migrate IBM RTC code with history to git with rtc2git?

Tags: git, rational-team-concert

So I need to migrate with history RTC to Git using the [rtc2git "Getting your History Files" page](https://github.com/rtcTo/rtc2git/wiki/Getting-your-History-Files).

However, I am not able to see the option how to do the below steps:

> - Select all Entries and press "Copy URL" in the context menu
> - Copy the links in a editor of your choice and remove everything except the uuid (marked green) of the changeset (use search and replace)
> - Save file as History_YourComponentname_YourStreamName.txt and place it in the folder called "History"
> - Repeat process for each component of your stream

Can someone confirm if there are able to migrate rtc code along with history to git using this process?

Answer (score 0):

I followed a similar process, without using rtc2git, by:

- creating a repository workspace on the stream to migrate
- replacing the baseline with a past baseline I want to import to Git
- import the content of the local repository workspace to Git repository
- repeat with a more recent baseline

The import itself is done with

```
cd /path/tonew/Git/repo
git --work-tree=/path/to/RTC/repo/workspace add .
git commit -m "Import RTC baseline xxx"
git tag -m "Import RTC baseline xxx" xxx
git push --follow-tags
```

The idea is to import only a few selected baselines I deem important, in order to get a shallow history in Git of the former RTC codebase.

RTC itself remains in read-only mode if one need to consult a detailed history in the past.

Comment: Thanks @VonC

My Question is simple, i have project code base in IBMRTC

Want to migrate one of the stream with history to git , so this can be migrated to aws codecommit at later Phase (so the history will be seen at git commits end)

so, what is the best approach to achieve this ?

have you implemented this task before can u please provide step by step procedure if you have info handy.
This is a major blocker for us to migrate the code from IBM RTC to git

Comment: can this task be achived ? or what needs to be done to achieve this.. please help us in providing more information

Comment: "so, what is the best approach to achieve this ?" The one highlighted in the answer: only  import a few significant baselines, not the full history of every files.

Comment: Hi VonC, can u help us in detailed way on how to migrate the existing RTC workspace stream to git repository (along with history)..

Comment: And i didnt really get what you mean by above, so please help me with more details and help us 
thanks in advance

Comment: @nag What I said above was: I am not migrating an RTC *full* history to a Git repository, only a few RTC baselines.

Comment: Hi VonC, can u help us in detailed way on how to migrate the existing RTC workspace stream to git repository (along with history)..                                                                       
have you done this task? if you how you accomplished. this is a blocker for us to migrate a project and its an impacting one         
steps u said --> but i didnt got how to do this

Comment: steps u said --> but i didnt got how to do this
creating a repository workspace on the stream to migrate
replacing the baseline with a past baseline I want to import to Git
import the content of the local repository workspace to Git repository
repeat with a more recent baseline
The import itself is done with

Comment: @nag " (along with history).. have you done this task?": No, I have not done this task, because the history model is too different between RTC and Git.

Comment: so when u say only few baselines --> have u done RTC workspace stream full history migration to a git repository? what is the difference between few baselines and full history?

Comment: @nag full history means every commit of every RTC change set. A few baselines means rebing your local  RTC repository workspace with a baseline in the past, import the content of your local repository workspace in a Git repo (commands listed in the answer), then repeat for another RTC baseline more recent.

Comment: Hi Vonc GM!    after i executed the migration.py file with all details  from https://github.com/rtcTo/rtc2git site i got the code but when i do the git history check command i don't see the history information

Comment: @nag That would be interesting as a separate question (I am not familiar with rtc2git, and limit my migration to import a few baseline only, not the full history)